# How can I properly access store actions in a Vue test?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex, vue-test-utils

I have a test that is passing, but I don't understand why I have to write this way.   Here is the test setup:

```
describe("Photo Due", () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();
  localVue.use(Vuex);
  let store;
  let actions = {
    "api_data/photoAction": jest.fn(),
    "api_data/selectPhoto": jest.fn(),
    "modals/openCloseModal": jest.fn()
  },
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        token: "abc",
        GLN: "123",
        GLT: "456",
        isDesktop: true
      },
      getters: {
        "auth/getToken": state => state.token,
        "auth/getGLN": state => state.GLN,
        "auth/getGLT": state => state.GLT,
        "app/getIsDesktop": state => state.isDesktop
      },
      actions
    });
  });
...
```

Here is my test that calls a function, which calls an action:

```
it("reportPhoto", async () => {
    const wrapper = factory();
    wrapper.vm.reportPhoto();
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    expect(actions["api_data/selectPhoto"]).toHaveBeenCalled();  // THIS IS THE LINE IN QUESTION
  });
```

When the test is setup this way everything passes.  But it doesn't seem right that I am defining actions outside of the store and accessing it that way in the test by calling `actions["api_data/selectSnap"]`.  I copied this approach from a guide on from the vue-test-utils website.  If I don't need to access actions and getters from the store then why not bypass the store altogether and jut define random functions that mock my vuex functionality?

I think I don't understand what is happening under the hood fully, but shouldn't I be accessing the action through the store?  This is what I am having trouble doing.

My questions are 1) Do I need to access the actions through the store or am I overthinking what should be a basic test?  2) If I do need to access the action through the store, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: There is a slightly different approach described in the Vuex documentation: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/testing.html

Comment: I would actually recommend a different guide: [https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vuex.html#testing-a-running-store](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vuex.html#testing-a-running-store). This is truly testing your existing store to the fullest, but presents its own challenges.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what kind of test you are trying to do and if you want to test a fully functional store or just check that it gets called.

I recommend [this post](https://medium.com/@abdulsamet.ileri/unit-testing-a-vue-component-with-vuex-using-vue-test-utils-and-jest-5433053535ec). There are differents  approach explained along with several examples. It helped me when I needed to write some store oriented unit tests